# Spring 3.2.4, EclipseLink 2.5, Glassfish 3.1.2 and JPA 2.1

Tags: java, spring, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I'm very new in the world of Spring and Glassfish. I've been fighting with the configuration of the one application using these topics, but I don't get create the application. Anybody can help me please?

I want to create an application with one persistence.xml, jndi data source, generic dao configuration.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code, but I think that there are some conflicts with the configuration.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="spartanPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__spartanDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.spartan.model.entities.SourceEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

**dao-bean.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true" default-autowire="no">

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="sourceDao" class="com.spartan.model.daos.SourceDao">
    <property name="entityClass" >
        <bean class="com.spartan.model.entities.SourceEntity" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
    default-autowire="no">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:annotation-config />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/__spartanDS" />

<import resource="classpath:com/spartan/model/spring/dao-beans.xml" />    

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spartanPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" /> 

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**BaseDao.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseDao<PK, T> implements IBaseDao<PK, T> {

protected T entityClass;

@PersistenceContext 
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public BaseDao() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
        .getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = ((T) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
}

@Transactional
public T create(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.persist(entity);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    return entity;
}

public T read(PK id) {
    return null;
}

public T update(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.merge(entity);
    this.entityManager.flush();     
    return entity;
}

public void delete(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.remove(entity);
}

public void setEntityClass(T entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

}
```

Actually with this configuration when I tried to persist something the glassfish server give me the next stack trace.

**Stack Trace**

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at $Proxy329.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at $Proxy327.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.spartan.model.daos.BaseDao.create(BaseDao.java:35)
    at com.spartan.web.controllers.MovieController.getMovie(MovieController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of things with your configuration

1. You have multiple `<tx:annotation-driven ../>` tags, this is at least confusing
2. `<context:annotation-driven ../>` already implies the `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` and `utowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.
3. The `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` is also already present (your config can lead to proxing a proxy)
4. What is it you want JTA or not? Your persistence.xml gives the impression you want JTA however you fail to configure a `JtaTransactionManager`, you have a `JpaTransactionManager` which is to be used for local transactions. Either remove JTA from persistence.xml or configure a JtaTransactionManager.
5. When you want JtaTransaction you need to set the `jtaDataSource` property of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead and you probably need some additional configuration for EclipseLink also.
6. In your dao don't call flush, persist should already directly go to the database, next to that flushing should be in general be left to the ORM provider itself.